# iOs(Swift) In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to test in-app-billing for non-consumable. In my project i have 5 contents to buy and then download.Upon clicking a button the user should buy the content.I followed Ray Wenderlich tutorial(https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial) and implemented with my build identifier its working fine. But when i implement the same code with UiButton action its not fetching the product information and getting error.  I can not seem to figure out what the problem is here. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.